# Python3 ImportError: No module named 'reinforcement_learning'

Tags: python, importerror

The following code:

```
#player2048.py file
from reinforcement_learning.rl.player_lib import Player
```

Give me the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'reinforcement_learning'
```

My project folder:

[image: This is my project's folder]

Comment: I changed the folders and stuffs, so just ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an `__init__.py` for the reinforcement_learning folder?

The way the screen shot was taken it could be cut off...

Comment: Yes, there is. As you can see: https://github.com/darleybarreto/deep-reinforcement-learning